# Location to edit xdebug.max_nesting_level in ubuntu 14.04 PHP using Lighttpd

Tags: 14.04, php, lighttpd, xdebug

I am getting

```
fatal error maximum function nesting level of '100' reached aborting..
```

It seems I have to edit

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level from 100 to more.
```

But I am unable to find the correct file in where I should edit this? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 , lighttpd webserver and Php..

From internet I saw I have to edit php.ini file in /etc/php5/apache2..

But I am using lighttpd.

In my /etc/php5/ there are three folders namely

1. cgi
2. cli
3. mods-available

In the cgi and cli folder there are php.ini file, But those 2 files did not contain anyting to edit xdebug.

In mods-available folder I got 1 file namely xdebug.ini and it just contains

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

So I need help how to edit xdebug.max_nesting_level in ubuntu 14.04 PHP and Lighttpd. Sorry for my bad English. Seeking your help to solve this

Comment: try "locate php.ini" in order to find php configuration file.

Comment: I mentioned that in my /etc/php/cgi/ there is a file named php.ini, but in that file there is nothing about xdebug configuration to edit that..

Comment: Yes, sorry, I suggest to locate file in order to check if there are other then the two you mentioned. Anyway, you did not find xdebug.max_nesting_level because this is a xdebug variable. So, I'm not sure, but try to add "xdebug.max_nesting_level = 150" in xdebug.ini after zend_extension and let's see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: But when I run phpinfo from localhost in browser there shows xdebug and all of its configuration including xdebug.max_nesting_level=100.. so I guess the configuration must be written somewhere.. Unfortunately I am not finding it yet ..

Comment: Yes, phpinfo show you default value for all xdebug variables, this means that xdebug.so extension is correctly loaded by php. You can not find these settings in any configuration file. Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 9):

To fix the issue, I edited `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` and added the following line:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250
```

Answer (score 3):

`phpinfo` show you default value for all xdebug variables, this means that `xdebug.so` extension is correctly loaded by php.

In order to change `xdebug.max_nesting_level` default settings open `xdebug.ini` and add:

```
 xdebug.max_nesting_level=150
```

Similarly, you can also change other xdebug variables.